# Orthogonal complement of linear subspaces of a Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$, $N$ be linear sub spaces of a Hilbert space $H$.

How to show that $$(M+N)^\perp= M^\perp\cap N^\perp?$$

Comment: This is pretty obviously false (look at lines in $\Bbb{R}^2$, say).

Comment: I'm sorry,there was a mistake.that should be the intersection.I've corrected it.

Comment: @ccc : See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246967/show-w-1-w-2-perp-w-1-perp-cap-w-2-perp-and-w-1-perp-w-2-perp/247717#247717)

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d\in (M+N)^{\perp}$ then, for $m\in M $ and $n\in N$, $(d,m+n)=0$. Take $n=0$ and then $m=0$ to conclude that $d\in N^\perp\cap M^\perp$.

On the other hand, if $d\in N^\perp\cap M^\perp$ then you have $d\in N^\perp$ and $d\in M^\perp$. This implies that $(d,n)=0$ and $(d,m)=0$ for $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, hence, $(d,n+m)=(d,n)+(d,m)=0$. Therefore $d\in (M+N)^{\perp}$

Comment: Thank you very much Tomas!

Comment: We should not answer such no-effort questions.