# Does $S^\bot+T^\bot = (S\cap T)^\bot$ hold in infinite-dimensional spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

If $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of some finite-dimensional inner product space then
$$S^\bot+T^\bot = (S\cap T)^\bot.$$
See, for example, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408973/w-1-perp-w-2-perp-w-1-cap-w-2-perp-can-a-set-be-a-function-can-tw) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898803/let-w-1-and-w-2-be-subspaces-of-a-finite-dimensional-inner-product-space-spa/)

> Does it hold in infinite-dimensional inner product spaces? What about Hilbert spaces?

---

My attempt:

I have noticed that $$S^\bot+T^\bot \subseteq (S\cap T)^\bot \subseteq (S^\bot+T^\bot)^{\bot\bot}$$ holds in any inner product space. So to find a counterexample, I need that $W=S^\bot+T^\bot$ fulfills $W\subsetneq W^{\bot\bot}$. A standard example I know, which fulfills this, is the set of all sequence with finite support in the inner product space $\ell_2$. However, I do not think that this space can be expressed as $S^\bot+T^\bot$ for some two subspaces.

I have tried to play around with some similar subspaces of $\ell_2$, but I did not find a counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not hold in general.

Recall two basic facts: for any subspace $E$ of a Hilbert space, we have that

1. $E^{\perp}$ is closed;
2. $E^{\perp\perp} = \bar{E}$, the closure of $E$.  In particular, if $E$ is closed then $E^{\perp\perp}=E$.

Now in
[The direct sum of two closed subspace is closed? (Hilbert space)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135471/the-direct-sum-of-two-closed-subspace-is-closed-hilbert-space),
you can find an example of two closed subspaces $X_1, X_2$ of a
Hilbert space $H$, such that $X_1 \cap X_2 = 0$ but $X_1 + X_2$ is not
closed.  Taking $S = X_1^\perp$, $T = X_2^\perp$, we have by fact 2
that $S^\perp =  X_1$ and $T^\perp = X_2$.  So $S^{\perp} + T^{\perp}
= X_1 + X_2$ is not closed.  On the other hand, by fact 1 $(S \cap
T)^\perp$ is necessarily closed.  In this case, since $S \cap T = 0$,
we have $(S \cap T)^\perp = H$ which is definitely closed.  So
$S^\perp + T^\perp \ne (S \cap T)^\perp$.